# Undefined method `is_numeric?'

Tags: ruby

I have the following two methods:

```
class OrderHelper
  def is_numeric?
    true if Float(self) rescue false
  end
  def order_number_or_name(order_ref)
    if order_ref.is_numeric?
      "Your Order Reference Number: "
    else
      "Your Order Reference Name: "
    end
  end
end
```

I am getting the following error:

```
undefined method `is_numeric?' for "85757858":String
```

How is `is_numeric?` undefined when I am declaring it right above the second method?

Comment: It's not a method on string, though; you've defined a helper method named `is_numeric?`. It would need an argument as written, e.g., you'd pass it `order_ref` and call `Float(order_ref)`. It sounds like you thought you were monkey-patching `String`.

Comment: @sawa don't remove the helper method file name.. You can put it there.. Tag it as ruby on rails also.

Comment: ok.. as you wish.. :D But rails helper are defined like the OP's one.. inside a module, which some where some how mixed in.. I don't know how although..( Just FYI). Not relevant in this case although.

Comment: Humm.. `order_helper.rb` means in rails those are in the module `OrderHelper`...

Comment: @sawa  hum hum.. time for dinner.. :D

Comment: Aside from your immediate problem, do all order numbers contain a single decimal point, preceded and followed by one or more digits? Even if they do (meaning you can see if `Float` raises an exception), I think the use of a regex here reads better and can be made more precise: e.g., `str =~ /^\s*\d{3,5}\.\d{2,3}\s*$/` requires strings to have between 3 and 5 digits before the decimal point and between 2 or 3 after. Also, unlike `Float`, it disqualifies `"-1.2"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the *helper* method `#is_numeric` is not an instance method of the `String` instances. Change your code to:

```
def is_numeric? order_ref
  true if Float(self) rescue false
end
```

And use it as below:

```
def order_number_or_name(order_ref)
  if is_numeric?(order_ref)
    "Your Order Reference Number: "
  else
    "Your Order Reference Name: "
  end
end
```

Comment: I don't think `!!Float(order_ref)` is any better than `true if Float(order_ref)`. The latter is better.

Comment: @sawa `rescue` is needed to handle the exception.. `Float(nil)` will throw a _type error_.